# I've started Tuples to LINQ and I'm not sure if it's an anti pattern

Tags: c#, linq

I have

```
public static class TupleExtensions {

    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T>(this IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> te)
    {
        foreach (var t in te)
        {
            yield return t.Item1;
            yield return t.Item2;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T, U>(this IEnumerable<U> source, Func<U, Tuple<T, T>> fn)
    {
        foreach (var s in source)
        {
            var t = fn(s);
            yield return t.Item1;
            yield return t.Item2;
        }

    } 

    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T, U>(this IEnumerable<U> source, Func<U, Tuple<T, T, T>> fn)
    {
        foreach (var s in source)
        {
            var t = fn(s);
            yield return t.Item1;
            yield return t.Item2;
            yield return t.Item3;
        }

    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T, U>(this IEnumerable<U> source, Func<U, Tuple<T, T, T,T>> fn)
    {
        foreach (var s in source)
        {
            var t = fn(s);
            yield return t.Item1;
            yield return t.Item2;
            yield return t.Item3;
            yield return t.Item4;
        }

    }
}
```

I can then do as a trivial example

```
IEnumerable<int> source = ...
source.SelectMany(i=>Tuple.Create(i, i+1, i+2))
```

Obviously the tuple must have the same types throughout. My use
case is where I have a mathematical solver which will always return
two solutions for a given input. Returning a list makes it unclear
how many solutions would be returned.

However in the end I would want all my solutions merged. For example

```
static Tuple<Point,Point> Intersect(this Shape shape, Line other);

Shape shape = ...
IEnumerable<Line> lines = ...

IEnumerable<Point> intersections = lines.SelectMany(line=>shape.Intersect(line));
```

Is there some good reason not to treat `Tuple<T,T,T....>` as a container that we can flatten?

Comment: I'd rather use collections (perhaps immutable, perhaps simple arrays).

Comment: No, there's no good reason not to consider tuples this way. If it seems "wrong" somehow, it's only because C# has such limited support for tuples. In a functional language, or one with better tuple support, this would seem very natural.

Comment: @CodesInChaos the problem with collections is that the length is not considered part of the type. If my function should always return two values but I return a List<Point> should the client of that code put in a check that there are in fact two values or risk an index out of bounds exception?

Comment: if you really want length to be part of the type, then create a custom type. Else simply go with `T[]` or `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Can you explain why you think Tuple is wrong for this? In C++ I could create a type with an integer type parameter with a recursive template definition. In C# that is not possible. How would you make a generic Container<T,length> type other than with Tuple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I think this pattern makes sense, because it clearly expresses what the method returns and lets you easily do the computation you want to do with the result.

Some thoughts:

1. I don't see any reason why your extension methods should only work on a collection of `Tuple`s and not on a single `Tuple`. Because of that, I would probably write extension methods that convert a single `Tuple` to `IEnumerable`:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this Tuple<T, T> tuple)
   {
       yield return tuple.Item1;
       yield return tuple.Item2;
   }
   ```

   Since this would make the code you showed more complicated, it might make sense to also keep `SelectMany()`, but express it using `ToEnumerable()`:

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T>(
       this IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> tuples)
   {
       return tuples.SelectMany(t => t.ToEnumerable());
   }

   public static IEnumerable<T> SelectMany<T, U>(
       this IEnumerable<U> source, Func<U, Tuple<T, T>> selector)
   {
       return source.SelectMany(x => selector(x).ToEnumerable());
   }
   ```
2. It might make sense to create custom types that mean “pair (triple, …) of items of the same type”. As a side benefit, you wouldn't need custom `ToEnumerable()` or `SelectMany()` extensions, since those types could implement `IEnumerable<T>` directly.

Comment: I like this. Shame that we can't create an implicit cast to IEnumerable<T> and all this would work automagically.

Comment: Isn't all you need `ToEnumerable`? 
`IEnumerable<Point> intersections = lines.SelectMany(line=>shape.Intersect(line).ToEnumerable());`
looks all right to me. What does all the rest give?

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca Yes, that works fine, but I think an overload of `SelectMany()` makes sense to make the code shorter, especially since the `Tuple` can be considered a sequence, so the `SelectMany()` does logically make sense.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing To be consistent with existing LINQ APIs you should use the semantics `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToEnumerable` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx ,  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873930/why-are-asobservable-and-asenumerable-implemented-differently ,